# Xdebug time out while running debug session (PhpFarm | phpFcgi)

Tags: docker, phpstorm, xdebug, phpfarm

I run apache Webserver inside of a docker container.
To be able to use multiple php-versions, I use phpfarm inside of this docker-container.

After I configured xdebug and connect it to phpstorm, I wonder why the debug-session allways finishd with a 500 error in the Browser.

The timeout was nearly 40 - 50 Seconds after I request the Webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to set the Timeout for the Server in the vhostfile for each php-version:

```
FcgidIOTimeout 300
```

With this parameter, the timeout isset to 300 Seconds.
Don't forget to restart or reload the Webserver.